# Irreducibility of product bicomodules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra, and $V$ and $W$ a left, and a right, 
$H$-comodule respectively. The tensor product
$$
V \otimes W
$$
has an obvious $H$-$H$-bicomodule structure.
If $V$ and $W$ are irreducible as left and right comodules, then
is $V \otimes W$ irreducible as a $H$-$H$-bicomodule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, off course, not. You need a slightly stronger condition. One of your comodules need to be absolutely irreducible.

To prove it, apply the fundamental theorem of coalgebra. The comodules give you simple subcoalgebras $C_M$ and $C_N$ in the coradical of $H$. You are asking for the algebra $(C^{\ast}_M)^{op}\otimes C^{\ast}_N$ to be simple.

For an elementary example let ${\mathbb R}$ be the ground field, $H$ the free cocommutative Hop algebra generated by the trigonometric coalgebra ${\mathbb C}^{\ast}$. Let $M=N={\mathbb C}$ be the $\mathbb C$-module, hence, ${\mathbb C}^\ast$-comodule, hence $H$-comodule. The $H$-bicomodule structure on $M\otimes N$ is essentially its module structure over ${\mathbb C}\otimes_{\mathbb R}{\mathbb C}\cong {\mathbb C}\oplus{\mathbb C}$. This is not irreducible because $dim(M\otimes N)=4$ but its simple modules are 2-dimensional.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see why what I am asking for is equivalent to $(C^*_M)^{op} \otimes C^*_N$ being simple. (Also, I guess $C^*_M$ denotes the linear dual of $C^*_M$ endowed with convolution multiplication?)

Comment: You are asking for $M\otimes N$ to be a simple $(C^{\ast}_M)^{op}\otimes C^{\ast}_N$-module.  And you know that $M\otimes N$ is a faithful finite-dimensional $(C^{\ast}_M)^{op}\otimes C^{\ast}_N$-module. Now simplicity of the algebra $(C^{\ast}_M)^{op}\otimes C^{\ast}_N$ implies simplicity of the module $M\otimes N$. In the opposite direction, hit it with Jacobson Density Theorem.

Comment: Yes or no, since you have a typo:  $C^{\ast}_M$ is the linear dual of coalgebra $C_M$.

Comment: Yes, it should read "$C^*_M$ denotes the linear dual of $C_M$".